# Is Baarle-Hertog/Baarle-Nassau the only case where businesses fall under multiple same-level jurisdictions because the border goes through them?

Tags: multiple-jurisdiction

Baarle-Hertog and Baarle-Nassau are an international village on the border between Belgium and the Netherlands where a store literally can be located in 2 countries at once: a Belgian part and a Dutch part. Lately, the COVID-19 crisis has caused a weird situation where stores in the Baarle-Hertog section must be closed, but the stores in Baarle-Nassau can stay open. In this case, the stores that are in both sections at once can remain open IF the front door is in Baarle-Nassau (front door determines where you live), BUT they need to close off the section that's located in Baarle-Hertog. I don't know whether this is because Belgium ordered all stores to be closed or because Belgium closed their border, but the end result is that these stores essentially can't sell part of their stock because it's located in the Belgian section.

I'm wondering whether there are other cases where a business that's located directly over the border between 2 legal entities with separate jurisdictions needs to adhere to 2 separate jurisdictions that might even conflict with each other. Someone thought Texarkana in the USA on the Texas/Arkansas border might have that, but they weren't sure themselves, and checking now it appears that the border runs right down the middle of a street at all times, so it might not apply here.

Comment: Wikipedia article on "line house" offers a Canada/US example.

Answer (score 1):

The [Haskell Free Library and Opera House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_Free_Library_and_Opera_House) was built on the border between Quebec and Vermont.

> A thick black line runs beneath the seats of the opera house and diagonally across the center of the library's reading room to mark the Canada–United States border.[4] The stage and half of the seats are in Canada, the remainder of the opera hall is in the US.

The library is [run by an American non-profit organization](https://haskellopera.com/support-the-library/), so it may not count as a "business" for your purposes.

The Wikipedia article also links to that of [La Cure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Cure), a town on the border between France and Switzerland, where the boundary divides a pub and the [Hotel Arbez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel_Arbez).  The hotel's honeymoon suite is so arranged that each half of the bed is on either side of the border.